# Red hat EnterPrise Edition 4 GCC compiler support utf8 with BOM

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

Does the Red Hat Enterprise Edition 4 gcc compiler support UTF8 with BOM files?

If yes, which gcc compiler version do I need to compile C++ files encoded in UTF8 with BOM?

I am currently using **gcc version 3.4.6** and it gives me the following errors:-

```
:1: error: stray '\239' in program
 1: error: stray '\187' in program
    error: stray '\191' in program
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that only [GCC versions 4.4 and above](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33415) support UTF-8 with BOM.

GCC 4.4 was introduced in [RHEL 6](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Developer_Guide/compilers.html), and it's also available in RHEL 5 as a separate package, `gcc44`. I don't know if there is a GCC 4.4 package also available for RHEL4.

In case you must use GCC 3.4.6, you may try to add a "preprocess" step in your build system that removes the BOM. A very simple example (taken from [here](http://www.linuxask.com/questions/how-to-remove-bom-from-utf-8)) would be:

```
tail --bytes=+4 source.cpp > sourceWithoutBOM.cpp
```